# Dynamically creating a trigger

Tags: trigger, rest-api, managed-package, tooling-api

I'm looking to add functionality to my managed package that would dynamically create a trigger based on user inputs. I've seen some conflicting answers about whether a trigger can be created using the REST or Tooling API, does anyone have any experience creating a trigger on the fly?

The functionality I'm looking for would allow them to set up a trigger within our app without the need for first writing the trigger in a sandbox, writing the test case, deploying, etc.

Comment: Did you manage to accomplish it ?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the Declarative roll up summary tool for an example of dynamically creating triggers

[Declarative roll up summary](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)

Answer (score 0):

The tooling API works great in Sandboxes and Dev orgs, but not in Enterprise orgs. I described how to do it with the SOAP API under another question [Dynamic Trigger Creation From Managed Package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155868/dynamic-trigger-creation-from-managed-package/271472#271472)